# Can you hide a QGroupBox frame but preserve it's content visible?

Tags: qt, groupbox

I have a `QGroupBox`. Depending on the context, it's title may be redundent (displayed in another place of the GUI), so I then need to make as if the `QGroupBox` was not here....but I must preserve it's content visible (so I don't want to call `QGroupBox::hide()`)!

I need to do this dynamically at runtime and would like to avoid creating/destroying the `QGroupBox` + reparenting it's content....there must be an easier way to do this.

What I tried so far:

`QGroupBox` visible:

[image]

- `QGroupBox::setTitle("")` removes the text.
- `QGroupBox::setFlat(true)` makes the frame be a single line.

I end up with this:

[image]

Not too bad...but a line remains....is there a way to completely hide the `QGroupBox` frame but preserve it's content visible?

Comment: I had a similar problem, what I end up doing is to place content in a QTableWidget. With QTablewidget, I can hide all borders.

Comment: @MasterAler: `QComboBox::setStyleSheet( "border: none" );` works just perfectly. If you add this as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @KubaOber: Just expecting to find something more trivial....as MasterAler proposed for instance.

Comment: @user3183610: `QGroupBox` can be made chackable, `QTableWidget` can't....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QFrame` + `QGridLayout` (or some more complex combination of layouts) + QSS instead of a `QGroupBox`.

Considering a `QGroupBox` only, a trivial solution via QSS could be:

```
static const char kSavedTitle[] = "_savedTitle";
void hideBoxFrame(QGroupBox * box) {
  box->setProperty(kSavedTitle, box->title());
  box->setTitle(QString());
  box->setStyleSheet("border:none");
}
void showBoxFrame(QGroupBox * box) {
  box->setTitle(box->property(kSavedTitle).toString());
  box->setStyleSheet(QString());
}
```

Answer (score 11):

My option:

```
QGroupBox theBox;
theBox.setFlat(true);
//This removes the border from a QGroupBox named "theBox".
theBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox#theBox {border:0;}");
//This removes the border from the group box and all of its children
theBox.setStyleSheet("border:0;");
```

Comment: Nice alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can derive your own Group Box from the `QGroupBox` and reimplement the `paintEvent()` method. It should be very simple. Original `QGroupBox::paintEvent()` looks like this:

```
void QGroupBox::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter paint(this);
    QStyleOptionGroupBox option;
    initStyleOption(&option);
    paint.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_GroupBox, option);
}
```

What you need to do is just to modify the style option right before the widget is painted:

```
void CMyGroupBox::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter paint(this);
    QStyleOptionGroupBox option;
    initStyleOption(&option);

    // This should disable frame painting.
    option.features = QStyleOptionFrame::None;

    paint.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_GroupBox, option);
}
```

Comment: That's an option, but more difficult to setup than applying a stylesheet as commented by MasterAler

Comment: Actually, this solution is approximately as trivial to implement as [MasterAler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846068/masteraler)'s [prior solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623476/2809027) but has the significant advantage of *not* hiding the frames of all child widgets. While simple, setting a stylesheet of `border:0` unconditionally applies that style to all child widgets. That's bad. While slightly less simple, this solution suffers no such critical defects. That's good.

Comment: how would i do this for the PyQt version? I am unsure of how to change the method, because the module doesn't have the logic...
`def paintEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QPaintEvent) -> None: ...`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that does it by swapping the widgets and reparenting the children. It works for any widget that has direct children, not only `QGroupBox`. It would require special case handling for widgets such as `QScrollArea` and `QMainWindow` that wrap children in a special sub-widget.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32584320/1329652) for a related discussion of programmatically promoting widgets.

[image: screenshot of the example]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/group-reparent-36603051
#include <QtWidgets>

/// Replaces the visible widget with a hidden widget, preserving the layout of the
/// children, and making the new widget visible.
void swapWidgets(QWidget * a, QWidget * b)
{
   auto src = a->isVisible() ? a : b;
   auto dst = a->isVisible() ? b : a;
   Q_ASSERT(dst->isHidden());
   /// Move the children to the destination
   dst->setLayout(src->layout());
   /// Replace source with destination in the parent
   auto layout = src->parentWidget()->layout();
   delete layout->replaceWidget(src, dst);
   /// Unparent the source, otherwise it won't be reinsertable into the parent.
   src->setParent(nullptr);
   /// Only the destination should be seen.
   src->hide();
   dst->show();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   QGridLayout wLayout{&w};
   QPushButton swapBtn{"Swap"};
   wLayout.addWidget(&swapBtn);

   QWidget noBox;
   QGroupBox box{"Group"};
   wLayout.addWidget(&box);
   QGridLayout boxLayout{&box};
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
      boxLayout.addWidget(new QLabel(QString("Tr%1").arg(i)), i/8, i%8);

   swapBtn.connect(&swapBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&] { swapWidgets(&box, &noBox); });
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a alternative that you can Try.

**You can morph into a QFrame which will keep the behavior But make the container boundaryless**

You can simply right click on the Group Box in the QDesigner and Select the 'Morph Into' option to select from

Comment: But QFrame won't let you display a title on the bar ("Emulator 0" in my screenshot)

Comment: that's true. But it looks like the easiest approach to do that with a label